# Using pulldata("@layer") function within Survey123 for offline use

Tags: offline, arcgis-survey123

Is there a way to use the pulldata("@layer") function in Survey123 for offline use?

We have field staff that are manually putting in information based on spatial boundaries are trying to save time and/or reduce human error by auto-populating fields with underlying data where each survey point is collected, in real time.

Other options would be post processing, but it would be nice for the field tech to see which area they are in, in on an autopopulated field based on their location.

Answer (score 1):

No.

[This ESRI page](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-survey123-blog/survey123-tricks-of-the-trade-pulldata-quot-layer/ba-p/1224415) explicitly states:

> No offline support: The pulldata("@layer") function only works while online. This makes it particularly useful for web surveys, although if your device is connected, it will also work in the Survey123 field app.